# How allow malayalam text only (Regex)

Tags: regex

RegExp("[\u0D00-\u0D7F]”)

Comment: inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[\u0D00-\u0D7F]”),),]  in flutter

Comment: `RegExp("^[\u0D00-\u0D7F]+$”)` ?

Comment: `RegExp(r"^[\u0D00-\u0D7F]*$", unicode: true)`

Comment: This question has the answer in this comment: `\p{Malayalam}` or `[\u0D00-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D44\u0D46-\u0D48\u0D4A-\u0D4F\u0D54-\u0D63\u0D66-\u0D7F]` or `[ഀ-ഌഎ-ഐഒ-ൄെ-ൈൊ-൏ൔ-ൣ൦-ൿ]` This avoids the unassigned code points `[\u0D0D\u0D11\u0D45\u0D49\u0D50-\u0D53\u0D64-\u0D65]` 10 of them, which is not a desirable match. Don't work at a rocket company if you're going to use `[\u0D00-\u0D7F]` you'd be fired instantly.